# Why does Rails / ActiveRecord accept an integer for a Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Why does ActiveRecord allow integers to be assigned to columns that are dates?  (I'm using sqlite3 in the dev environment.)

Here is the Schema:

```
 create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "segment"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    # ...
  end
```

If I do this in the Rails console:

```
e = Entry.new(user_id: 1, segment: 2, date: 42)
```

I get this

```
#<Entry:0x00000001139b16f8                                 
 id: nil,                                                  
 date: 42,                                                 
 segment: 2,                                               
 user_id: 1,                                               
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil> 
3.1.2 :065 > e.date.class
 => Integer
```

and I can `save!` this record with no issues.

If I do this:

```
e = Entry.new(user_id: 1, segment: 2, date: "2023-05-06")
```

I get this:

```
#<Entry:0x00000001143d6cf0
 id: 1,
 date: Sat, 06 May 2023,
 segment: 2,
 user_id: nil,
```

which makes sense, since there is an obvious coercion.

And, if I do this:

```
Entry.new(id: 1, segment: 2, date: "not a date")
```

I get this

```
#<Entry:0x000000011443e440                                                    
 id: 1,                                                                       
 date: nil,                                                                   
 segment: 2,                                                                  
 user_id: nil,
```

which makes sense because there's *not* an obvious conversion to `Date`.

So, why is an integer stored as an integer in a column configured as a date rather than either being converted into a date, or defaulted to `nil`?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: The dev sqlite3 database.

Comment: > SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values: INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I'd strongly recommend installing whatever database you're going to be deploying with so that you can develop, test, and deploy with the same database.

Comment: That all makes sense.  However, a String gets converted either to an integer or nil. Either ActiverRecord, or the sqlite3 drivers don't seem to support storing a date as text.